# Deploying Parse server to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, parse-server

I'm setting up a parse server to Google App Engine and I'm having trouble with the values needed for the Environment Variables in the app.yaml file.

Example:

```
env_variables:
# Your MongoDB URI
DATABASE_URI: mongodb://user:password@123.456.78.901:27017/db

# Absolute path to your cloud code main.js file
CLOUD_PATH: /Users/Name/MyCloudCode/cloud/main.js

# Parse App id
APP_ID: vd234kb78ud63bti76shwExample

# master key
MASTER_KEY: 843nte7fdgdsufy3vrfdsjkExample

# file key
# FILE_KEY: <your-file-key> (I can't find this one)

# Mount path for Parse API
PARSE_MOUNT_PATH: /parse
```

In terminal when I run `npm start` I get the error `throw 'You must provide an appId and masterKey!';`. Should the keys be < like this? > or 'like this' or something?
I've read through the Parse Migration guide but haven't been able to solve this problem.

Thanks!

**Edit:** If you want to downvote, at least point me in the correct direction to ask for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with npm not reading the yaml file (as that is only read by google app engine)

I asked same question on github and got this reply:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/issues/63

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the link and found that I needed to do `export MASTER_KEY=foo` and `export APP_ID=foo` before `npm start`. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the file key from the url to any file you had uploaded to your Parse app.

```
http://files.parsetfss.com/<your-file-key>/<parse-image-name>-hello.png.
```

Not sure if there's a cleaner way to get it, but that should work.